# PHP/MySQL IP to country for Stats page

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently converting a script for someone else and in their old code they had a CSV file listing all IPs and their countries. The file was in this format:

```
16777216    17367039    AU  AUS AUSTRALIA
17367040    17432575    MY  MYS MALAYSIA
17432576    17498111    AU  AUS AUSTRALIA
17498112    17563647    KR  KOR REPUBLIC OF KOREA
17563648    17825791    CN  CHN CHINA
```

Fine, that's what they did, I imported it to the new MySQL DB. But problem is they have 111K records here!

To do the comparison and find IP to country it takes around 40 seconds. Currently they select all records and compare to less than and more than the next field.

```
$datafile = file("iplist.csv");
    $countries = array();
    foreach($datafile as $data) {
        $data = explode(",", $data);
        foreach($iplist as $ipan => $ip) {
            if($ip > $data[0] && $ip < $data[1]) {
                $countries[$ip] = array($data[2], $data[4]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course I know this is a HORRIBLE way to do this, horrible! It's even bad when I do it in MySQL, I mean 111K records just sitting there.

I've been wracking my brain all day and can't think of anyway better to do this. IPs are stored in the DB in standard format. I thought I would just do a select from MySQL and in the where statement do a more than and less than. But for the life of me I can think of how. Considering this is how they make their IP list:

```
foreach($log as $row) {
        $iplist[$row[2]] = $row[2];

        if($last != "") {
            $dif = $last-$row[5];
            $avgtime += $dif;
        }
        $last = $row[5];
    }
```

I thought of doing one call per record, but if there are a normal of 120 records that come out on each stat page then that's out since that would be 120 calls to mysql minimum.

Can anyone give me a better and more efficient way to get this comparison?

I was thinking of using an outside service, but the requests would be so much I think the site would get blacklisted.

Comment: why not just import it directly? you didn't stated why you need to compare the IP.

Comment: Because on the stats page it has to show which country the visitor is from. Hence the IP to country code. The PHP script has to figure out which country the IP came from for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

WHy not try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ip_min >= $your_value and ip_max <= $your_value
```

Where `ip_min` would be that first column of data and `ip_max` is the 2nd column.  `$your_value` would obviously be the ip value that is known to you.

Also with regards to geoIP location, why not look to one of the standard databases like MaxMind. I personally like to handle the country ip geoLocation on the web server using the `mod_geoip` module with MaxMind database.  You can then just update this database on a monthly basis and not have to worry about trying to keep a current IP Database in your application.  `mod_geoip` simply exposes a few additional value into the `$_SERVER` superglobal that you can read to get country code or country name (or even down to city).

Comment: This works yes, but can you imagine calling MySQL select statement once for every record grabbed from the db? 120 min records each time the stats page is displayed. I've tested this, this also takes 30 to 40 seconds to display the page.

Comment: @jfreak53 see my updated answer for commentary on ways to move this out of the database altogether. I guess I didn't follow what you were meaning by 120 records originally.  Yes, if you were trying to process ip's in bulk (rather than per script execution), nothing really straightforward comes to mind.

Comment: That's the other problem, that would require apache module, we don't have access to that. Not to mention I kinda think that might be slow also, not sure though since I have never tested. My thought has been if there was a way to grab the smallest IP then the largest IP from the IP list then grab from mysql those records that are between those two number. Just not sure how to do that really. `BETWEEN` in mysql only works for dates I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should use join in your mysql query:

```
SELECT s.*, g.country_code, g.country_name FROM stats s LEFT JOIN geoip g ON ( g.ip_min <= s.ip AND g.ip_max >= s.ip )
```

Then you'll have it in one query.

Faster would be use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` but then it won't select record with ip out of range

Anyway I think it would be much better to find that location before inserting to stats table and assign ID of country with stats record - you'll also have to join it, but it will work much faster

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this before now!! Thanks. It works yes the problem being that it still takes 1 min. 50 sec. to do the search :(, that's with `inner`. EDIT: Oh, and that's only 5 records `limit 5` ;) Thanks though

Comment: do you have index on (ip_min, ip_max) ?

Comment: try play with `EXPLAIN` query (like `EXPLAIN SELECT s.*, g.country_code, g.country_name FROM...`) and you'll see if mysql is using any key/index, also you can try to use `BETWEEN` instead of >= and <= .

Comment: Yeah, I've got indexes on all the columns involved. Here is what `EXPLAIN` gives me: [link](http://pastebin.com/Tz5yp13F) My query is: [link](http://pastebin.com/8jcTwxRh)